# Bypass Edge Chromium profile Sign in screen in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, profile

I am trying to test a webapp in Edge (Chromium) using Selenium with Java

I am stuck inside an SOE which has annoying group policies enabled. When I open edge from Windows it goes straight in and I noted in the execution target, it's set to -profile-directory=Default, however when I launch with Selenium, it gets stuck on this screen

[Sign in to Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv31G.png)

So as I understand it, Selenium starts with a clean browser with no profile which is why the Group Policy blocks it

So I thought easy peasy I will just start Edge in a Private Window (which is really what I want anyway so I tried all the following options and it still opens the Sign in to Profile prompt)

```
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--inprivate");
options.addArguments("-inprivate");
```

So I thought then ok, set the same flag:
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default"); or options.addArguments("-profile-directory=Default"); still the same

So I thought I should try to tell it where the Profile is but the problem is when I go to where the profile should be:
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data, there is no Profile dir there

So if I go and make a new profile in Edge, it creates the dir Profile 1 even though in the UI, the Profile name is Profile 2 but that doesnt work it still just prompts me when I start Selenium saying I need to sign in

I have tried a bunch of other stuff that also doesnt work such as:

```
--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir
--ignore-user-profile-mapping-for-tests
```

The only thing that does work to bypass the sign into profile screen is if I use only this option:
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data");

Without specifying:

```
"--profile-directory=Profile 1"
```

and it actually goes straight into the browser! Except now I get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '<HOST>', ip: '<IP>'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--user-data-dir=C:\Users\<USER DIR>...], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--user-data-dir=C:\Users\<USER DIR>...], extensions: []}}}]

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:146)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:46)
at au.com.energyq.WebTestMain.beforeClass(WebTestMain.java:36)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Test ignored.

Test ignored.
```

Now when I google this error, it suggested my edge driver is not the same version of edge I am using but it is! 106.0.1370.42 and Edge is the same.

I am using Selenium 4.6.0

I know the webdriver works because when I do get that sign into profile prompt, If I manually sign in and the browser opens, the tests run!

I noticed in the stack trace it reckons I am sending the argument --allow-profiles-outside-user-dir but I am not!

Is the only way to get around this to get my IT to remove this group policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out!

So I had to still put:

```
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");
```

Then I put:

```
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
```

It works, opens Edge with the Default Profile, no prompt to sign in. I then put:

```
options.addArguments("--inprivate");
```

And it will open Edge in an In Private window all good!

I still tried the options.addArguments("--inprivate"); just by itself but it still would not work to just open an inprivate window and still prompts to Sign in to a profile.

Comment: `options.addArguments("--inprivate");` is privatemode and override profiles so it is enough.