# How to set edge capabilities in application.properties file of QMetry framework? - I want to bypass the profile sign-in window for edge browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, ui-automation, qaf

We can set chrome capabilities like

> chrome.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--disable-web->security","--user-data-dir=c:/temp/%RANDOM%"]}}

In similar way, I want to add the capabilities for edge WebDriver

Also, how can I bypass the sign-in window which is displayed when the edge WebDriver initiates and the browser opens, as the browser starts totally fresh, so the profile would not be logged in I believe.

I tried setting the capabilities like

> edge.additional.capabilities={"ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--user-data->dir=c:/temp/%RANDOM%"]}}

but it's throwing errors like

```
unable to create driver instance at 1st attempt
msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `%RANDOM%` with some value. For example:

```
edge.additional.capabilities={"ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--user-data-dir=c:/temp/temp12345"]}}
```

If it works, You can try providing random string. In property you can use `rnd` prefix, for example `${rnd:aaaaaaaa}` this will generate 8 char random string. Your capabilities may look like below:

```
edge.additional.capabilities={"ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--user-data-dir=c:/temp/${rnd:aaaaaaaa}"]}}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error as – 'The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed'.
If I comment the capability line, then its working fine.

Comment: And also if you know how to bypass that sign-in window, tell me how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: Refer answer to similar question for by pass sign in sceen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74398539/861594 
If that works then json represent for capability as per that answer is : `{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\${user.name}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data","--profile-directory=Default","--inprivate"]}}`

Comment: Added - 
{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","ms:edgeOptions":{"args":["--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\${user.name}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data","--profile-directory=Default","--inprivate"]}}

For this I'm getting error like - Microsoft Edge can't read or write to its data directory: "<userdata path>"
I'm not the admin so that may be the reason