# Bypass Edge Chromium profile Sign in screen in Selenium 4 Java(MacOS)

Tags: java, microsoft-edge, profile, selenium4

I know this question has been [answered for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368901/bypass-edge-chromium-profile-sign-in-screen-in-selenium-java/74398539#74398539). Every time I try to automate Edge browser using Selenium 4, I get shown a profile window to select and then to sign in.

In Windows, you need to pass in the `options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");`

to the options arguments followed by

`options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");`

But has anyone solved it for MacOS? Could not find a `User Data` folder under `/Users/<USER>/Library/Application support/Microsoft Edge/` folder. It directly has `Profile 1` folder for me. I tried various permutations and combinations to set the `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory` Nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Hi @Gajendra Varadhan, may I know if my answer is helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific path should be based on your **Profile path** at edge://version, regardless of OS.

For example, if you go to edge://version, and your **Profile path** is `/Users/<USER>/Library/Application support/Microsoft Edge/Profile 1`, your `options` should look like:

```
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=\\Users\\<USER>\\Library\\Application support\\Microsoft Edge");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1");
```

Additionally, it looks like you have [BrowserSignin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#browsersignin) configured among your group policies. It would be easier to not configure this policy if possible.

Comment: This worked! Although, I still need to figure out the sign in part still. Thanks.